# php mysql migration process

Tags: php, mysql

I have 18 tables in MySQL database, if admin change connection strings I need to move all tables contents to new target source.

What is the most efficient way handle this ?

- Get all create and insert  statements of tables and execute it in new
  server ?(*I think it is, how can I get statements(create + insert) of tables in MySQL)
- Send all rows in all tables iteration within loops?(it sounds bad, but solution is solution)

Is there any plugin or special function to make it faster in php5 PDO ?

(PHP 5.6.12 PDO)

Comment: Do you know how to use `mysqldump`?  Its purpose is your first listed option https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html  This database migration task does not usually involve PHP code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski till now, no. this exports all datatabse right ? I am on it. but can you share your experience or a bit close these experience or etc ?

Comment: @Drew yes this is what I exactly do... I will set a flac current connection string '0'(means passive) and create new cs as '1' after a bit process maybe next day, this magic will happen

Comment: I regret using the word pathetic. Please forgive

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ The page that Michael Berkowski linked has instructions for dumping only specified databases, if you read it.

Comment: @Drew don't worry I forgive you.

Comment: @Mark still reading it

Comment: read it all you want (i did not). But if a user connects, you need to rewrite mysql source code to do on the fly db transfers, unless I am delusional

Comment: @Drew You could use PHP to execute MySQL commands on the server, but I agree with your earlier statement and would like to know why the user is changing the connection string to begin with.

Comment: but @Mark would agree with this, if a user runs an isolated connection command, to an unknown db, ... see where that is going. The devil is in the details (lacking)

Comment: @Drew Well I never said it was a GOOD idea...just that it was an idea. :) The answer to every "Can you do this with programming?" question is always yes. The variables are Time, Money, Security, and Quality.

Comment: you guys confusing me.. here is the scenario system admin have able to change datasource so how you call this process migration db move all datas to another place or etc. if you were what would you do look at this way please..

Comment: that is not your question. Your question was `if a user change connection strings I need to move all tables`

Comment: so you are the one confusing things

Comment: @Drew ok I edit it for you but user defines a person who able to do this process it does not matter you call him as user or administrator.

Comment: oh it is a huge difference. We are living in little text boxes here, and lack telepathy powers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP isn't the best tool for this.

You can use PHP to collect data from the user, but then I would fire off a separate process in a shell script to run all the MySQL command line tools designed for this purpose. Pass your user data to the shell script as command line parameters. The exec() PHP function can start an async process so that your PHP script can carry on and not have to wait.

I came across this bit of code for starting async processes with PHP that has been pretty handy.
https://gist.github.com/wesdean/a319e171fffcf3c70919

- mysqldump - exports the database to a file on the file system.
- mysql - runs queries, including the import scripts created by mysqldump.

From the shell script you set up and manipulate your new database however you like.